# Using a Prolog predicate by providing the output and receiving the input

Tags: prolog

I wrote a Prolog predicate which transforms a list of digits in a number. So, for example, if the input is the list `[1, 2, 3]` then the output will be the number `123`. This is my code:

```
convertListToNum([], Col, Col).

convertListToNum([H|T], Col, R):-
    Col2 is Col * 10 + H,
    convertListToNum(T, Col2, R).

convertListToNumMain(L, R):-
    convertListToNum(L, 0, R).
```

As you can see, the arguments of the predicate are `L=input, R=output`, since I provide the list `L` as input into `ConvertListToNumMain` and I will get as output the number in `R`. If I try this predicate, it works as expected: `convertListToNumMain([1, 2, 3], R)` will give as output `R=123`.

Now what I want to do is use this function by providing the output number instead of the input list. I will use `L=output, R=input`. So I will not provide the list `L` anymore, I will provide the number `R` and expect to receive the list as output. So what I want is to call this: `convertListToNumMain(L, 123)` and I expect to receive as output `L=[1, 2, 3]`. However, when I call this I get the error `Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated`. I assume it is because in the line `Col2 is Col * 10 + H` I try to work with the first element of the list even tough the list is not instantiated, but I am not sure. What can I do to make this work?

I want to convert a list of digits to a number and then the number back to a list of digits and I thought I could get away with this, but apparently not. The alternative is to create another complex and inefficient predicate which will at each step find the most significant digit of a number, then add it to the list, find that number without that most significant digit and then make the next call. Or at least that is my idea. That is a lot of code and (it seems to me) more inefficient. So is there any way I can use what I already have by providing the output? If not, is there a better way than my idea above to convert a number into a list of digits (recursively, of course, since I'm using Prolog)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not that complicated. Or inefficient.

```
int_list( N , Ds ) :- nonvar(N), number_to_digits(N,Ds).
int_list( N , Ds ) :- nonvar(Ds), digits_to_number(Ds,0,N).

digits_to_number( [] , N , N ) .
digits_to_number( [D|Ds] , T , N ) :-
  T1 is 10 * T + D ,
  digits_to_number(Ds,T1,N).

number_to_digits( 0 , [0] ).
number_to_digits( N , Ds  ) :-
  N > 0,
  digits(N, [], Ds).

digits( N , T  , Ds ) :-
  N > 0,
  D  is N mod 10,
  N1 is N div 10,
  digits(N1,[D|T],Ds).
digits( 0 , Ds , Ds ) .
```

But it might be easier to use built-in predicate `number_codes/2`:

```
int_digits( N , Ds ) :- nonvar(Ds) , codes_digits(Cs,Ds) , number_codes(N,Cs)  .
int_digits( N , Ds ) :- nonvar(N)  , number_codes(N,Cs)  , codes_digits(Cs,Ds) .

codes_digits( []     , []     ) .
codes_digits( [C|Cs] , [D|Ds] ) :- code_digit(C,D), codes_digits(Cs,Ds).

code_digit(C,D) :- nonvar(C), D is C-48.
code_digit(C,D) :- nonvar(D), C is D+48.
```

Comment: `int_list(N,L)` fails.